# Isabelle: transpose a matrix that includes a constant factor

Tags: matrix, isabelle, theorem-proving

In my Isabelle theory I have a matrix with a constant factor:

```
... 
k :: 'n and c :: 'a
(χ i j. if j = k then c * (A $ i $ j) else A $ i $ j)
```

I can calculate the transposed matrix:

```
(transpose (χ i j. if j = k then c * (A $ i $ j) else A $ i $ j))
```

In my eyes the latter should be equivalent to

```
(χ i j. if i = k then c * (A $ j $ i) else A $ j $ i))
```

by the definition of `transpose`. But this is not true. What is my error here?

By the way, the definition of transposed is:

```
definition transpose where 
  "(transpose::'a^'n^'m ⇒ 'a^'m^'n) A = (χ i j. ((A$j)$i))"
```

Comment: Which matrix theory are you using?

Comment: Found it! The one from HOL-Multivariate_Analysis right?

Comment: I worked till 6 a.m (Europe) to find my problem, then wrote the question and went to bed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by: *But this is not true*. What you expected **is** true and can be proven in Isabelle as follows:

```
lemma "transpose (χ i j. if j = k then c * (A $ i $ j) else A $ i $ j) =
  (χ i j. if i = k then c * (A $ j $ i) else A $ j $ i)"
  by (simp add: transpose_def)
```

Comment: thank you very much. really! I did not explicitly state the lemma you have written in your reply. With it, my reduction step in the Isar proof works now. I thought some automatic proof heuristic would be enough for my reduction step and tried to just state "unfolding transpose_def" in my reduction step. thanks again!

Comment: `unfolding` really just rewrites the given equations from left-to-right. It can never conclude a proof.